Ubuntu Network issue which seems to occur randomly
I dont really know about networks so not sure how to diagnose this, but my internet doesn't work at times. I've seen the following problems:
On browsers (Firefox and Chrome) websites don't load at times unless I do a refresh without cached content multiple times; it just directly says "Unable to connect An error occurred during a connection to stackoverflow.com. " (or any other site) without even trying to load.
Other things like ssh also stop working randomly and I cant get them to work at all unless I restart the computer. Sometimes I am using copilot on vscode and it stops working in a similar manner.
Even ping doesn't work. When this happens I can access some sites but not others. For example ping google.com works at the same time that ping 8.8.8.8 gives ping: connect: Network is unreachable

@user535733 not there in my other devices so I assumne its not a non ubuntu issue. I have no clue where to begin looking, and none of the command outputs I find on related posts make any sense to me to know if they matter; do you have any suggestions

For interactive (conversational) help to troubleshoot your specific problem, try Ubuntuforums.org, our sister support venue. If, instead, your question is simply intended to generate a long list of things to check, please say so clearly in your AskUbuntu question.
